# Keyboard-indicator draining battery laptop

Tags: unity

After upgrade from 22.10 to 23.04 system keep cooler working all the time, draining battery.Checking `top` command at terminal , show output:

[image]

Since it was not fresh install , i decided to do a fresh install keeping HOME folder as it is in separated partition , but the same result. Any idea ?

System info:
Ubuntu unity 23.04
Linux notebook 6.2.0-24-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC